# authentication issues from getting a json result

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i got a problem with my login script in a platform of creating native mobile app
the server side work perfectly 
[here is my test with postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgAt4.jpg)

and this is the function that should redirect me to another page bit it don't

```js
function auth() {
  var login = js.getProperty('username', 'value');
  var password = js.getProperty('password', 'value');
  var url = 'http://meanlast.gear.host/user/login';
  url = url + '&login=' + login + '&password=' + password;
  var response = js.getDataFromUrl(url);
  var jsonRep = JSON.parse(response);
  if (jsonRep == "Login successful!") {
     js.alert("ok");
    js.navigateToPage('menu');
  } else {
    js.alert("error");
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON being returned from the page? It's not likely at all that after parsing JSON into an object that you are just left with a string.

Comment: This code looks wrong. `js.getDaraFromUrl(url);` wouldn't be a blocking function since it appears to be an attempted endpoint call. As such, all lines after it should be in a callback or a promise resolution.

Comment: from the platform this the error i get from the platform

                  Alert 
SyntaxError: Empty JSON string 
(jsEventsHandler#62)



and this is what i should get from the server
http://i.stack.imgur.com/UgAt4.jpg

Comment: @jpodwys do u have a suggestion plz to how should i do it

Comment: Without seeing the `js` object you're using in your demo, I can't understand what `js.getDataFromUrl` is doing. I'd start with the answer from @epascarello below first. If that doesn't work then your attempted ajax call is probably not executed correctly.

Comment: and it's the same problem with trying to show the result from server
function test() {
  var login = js.getProperty('username', 'value');
  var password = js.getProperty('password', 'value');
  var url = 'http://meanlast.gear.host/user/login';
  url = url + '&login=' + login + '&password=' + password;
  var response = js.getDataFromUrl(url);
  var jsonRep = JSON.parse(response);
 js.alert(jsonRep);
}

Comment: this is what i use in my server:

router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        err: info
      });
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          err: 'Could not log in user'
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Login successful!'
      });
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
 var url = 'http://meanlast.gear.host/user/login';
 url = url + '&login=' + login + '&password=' + password;
```

produces

```
"http://meanlast.gear.host/user/login&login=login&password=password"
```

Do you see the problem with your querystring? You do not have a `?`